# How to keep StatefulSnippet var values when redirecting through Javascript

Tags: javascript, scala, lift

I have an image link that when i click it i want to do some changes in some class variables and then redirect to other page and use those values.

Here is my code, im using StatefulSnippet

```
class MySnippet extends StatefulSnippet {

  var selectedStudent: Student=null

  def students =
    ".tabla" #> studentsList.map { s =>
      "#id" #> s.Id &
      "#name" #> s.Name & 
      "#surname" #> s.Surname &
      "#buttonAcademic [src]" #> tickUrl &
      ".clickableAcademic [onclick]" #> SHtml.onEvent(onClickCallbackAcademic(s))
    }

  def onClickCallbackAcademic(student: Student,xhtml:NodeSeq)(s: String): JsCmd = {
    //makes some stuff to student
    selectedStudent = student
    JsCmds.RedirectTo("/Academic")
  }

}
```

But when I redirect to the other page, my var selectedStudent is null, i tried debugging and selectedStudent has the correct value but when redirecting it turns null. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StatefulSnippet using HTML form and hidden parameter  to pass information (which snippet instance should be used) to server side of Lift.

So a JS redirect will not work, because it will not pass those information.

Here are some solution comes in my mind that may work in this case:

- Wrapping a form outside of  and submit it by JS in your onClickCallbackAcademic.
- Instead of using StatefulSnippet, use SessionVar to store your selectedStudent, so you could use it without form submit.